# Manipulating series to find the recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recursion

Ok so I am stuck. I need to get all the $n$'s to $=0$ but I can't reduce my series which has $n=2$ to $0$ because then I will have undone all my work in the first place to get all the $X^n$'s to the same power.. I am really confused on what to do.. Here is where I'm at now:

$$\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} n(n-1)a_nX^n + \sum ^{\infty}_{n=0} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}X^n - 6\sum ^{\infty}_{n=0} na_nX^n + 10 \sum ^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nX^n$$

any guidance would be great. Thx in advance

Comment: It is much easier to get all the n's to 2

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense, because then I wouldnt have my X's to the same power.

Comment: Why would you have to change the powers?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't just change $n =0 $ to $n=2$ without adding $n-2$ to everywhere there is a $n$ right??

Comment: The powers are all n so it doesn't matter.

Comment: When you reduce $n=2$ to $n=0$ you put a $+2$ everywhere there is a $n$ right? so similarly if you go from $n=0$ to $n=2$ don't you put a $-2$ everywhere there is a $n$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. See my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} n(n-1)a_nX^n + (2a_2+6a_3+\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}X^n) - (a_1+6\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} na_nX^n) + (a_1+10\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2}a_nX^n)$$

$$=(2a_2+6a_3)+\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} [n(n-1)a_nX^n +  (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}X^n) - (6 na_nX^n) + (10a_nX^n)]$$

$$=(2a_2+6a_3)+\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} [n(n-1)a_n +  (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}) - (6 na_n) + (10a_n)]X^n$$

Now you go about solving your differential equation:

$$(2a_2+6a_3)=0\rightarrow a_2=-3a_3$$

$$\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} [(n^2-7n+10))a_n + (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}) ]X^n=0\sum ^{\infty}_{n=2} [(n-5)(n-2)a_n + (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}) ]X^n=0$$

$$(n-5)(n-2)a_n + (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2})=0\rightarrow a_{n+2}=-\frac{(n-5)(n-2)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n$$

Comment: @user3325915 Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Yea I'm looking at it in detail. I see it now.

Comment: @user3325915 You know what to do now right?

Comment: Yea. Give me 4 mins. Working it out

Comment: shouldn;t you have $a_0+a_1 + 10$?

Comment: don't you plug in the $0$ for $n$ too ?

Comment: Yes it should be $a_0$ sorry

Comment: Do you want me to go back and change it, or are you good?

Comment: I think i'm good il brb

Comment: Yea can you edit it with the $a_0$ incorporated.

Comment: ∑n=2∞[(n2−7n+10))an+(n+2)(n+1)an+2)]Xn=0 I feel like should have +a_0

Comment: I'm getting $a_{n+2} = \frac{-(n-2)(n-5)a_n - 1}{(n+2)(n+1)}$ by the way we are also told that $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 0$ I forgot to mention that

Comment: Also for $a_2$ i got $a_2 = \frac{-11}{2}$ you getting the same thing?

Comment: So then what you said $a_2 = -3a_3$ cant be true? I'm so confused.